# AWX: ansible lookup to access extra environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-secrets-manager, ansible-awx

On my local machine I set the following environment vars:

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY='xxxx'
export AWS_SECRET_KEY='xxxx'
export AWS_REGION='us-east-1'
```

then in a playbook I put this:

```yaml
...
tasks:  
  - name: Get some secrets
    vars:
      db_password: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'DB_PASSWORD') }}"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ db_password }}"
...
```

When running the playbook the connection to AWS secrets works just fine, the necessary AWS variables are taken from the environment and I get the proper value in `db_password`.

When I'm trying to do the same in AWX, I set the above three variables in the section `Settings > Job Settings > Extra Environment Variables`:

```yaml
{
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY": "xxx",
  "AWS_SECRET_KEY": "xxx",
  "AWS_REGION": "us-east-1"
}
```

Now, when I'm running a playbook from AWX containing the above code `"{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'DB_PASSWORD') }}"` I get the error that I need to specify a region and if I set the region manually like `"{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'DB_PASSWORD', region='us-east-1') }}"` I get the error that AWX can't find the credentials.
So, for some reason these three variables are not read from the extra environment variables.

To make it work I had to write the following code in the playbook:

```yaml
region: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_REGION') }}"
aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_KEY') }}"
db_password: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'DB_PASSWORD', aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key, region=region) }}"
```

But I don't like this solution and I would prefer to avoid to explicitly set those three vars in the lookup and somehow tell AWX to take these three values from the extra environment variables. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm running in to a similar issue trying to set up proxmox dynamic inventory in AWX.

Comment: @ebarrere Unfortunately not. I'm still using exactly the same approach as described in the question.

Comment: Got it; thanks for the answer. After a lot of searching I did find a way to get the custom credential to inject to an environment variable — the key is to use "env:" instead of "extra_vars:" in your injector configuration.